# An additional row is added to datagrid after clicking any button

Tags: datagrid, row

I have a popup datagrid that allows users to add information to a database.  It works perfectly except the user has to hit "Accept" twice. The first time it adds another row, the second time it preforms the correct functions. (User can hit any button on the screen and it will add that extra row) What to do?

XAML

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="17"          AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                              Margin="15" Name="addProductDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"  Visibility="Collapsed" CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodNameColumn1" Binding="{Binding One}" Header="Name" Width="250"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodPriceColumn1" Binding="{Binding Two}" Header="Price" Width="100" />
         <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="prodCategoryNameColumn1" Binding="{Binding Three}" Header="Category" Width="200"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

CODE

```
AddInput.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
_currentDataGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
MenuDirectEntities db = new MenuDirectEntities();
BindingList<product> tempproduct = new BindingList<product>();
BindingList<Category> tempCategory = new BindingList<Category>();

            String productName = "";
            Decimal price = 0.00M;
            String categoryName = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < addProductDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBlock x = addProductDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(addProductDataGrid.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
                if (x != null)
                {
                    if (!x.Text.Equals(""))
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
                       // Console.WriteLine("Product " + i + ": " + x.Text);
                        productName = x.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                TextBlock y = addProductDataGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(addProductDataGrid.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
                if (y != null)
                {
                    if (!y.Text.Equals(""))
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine("Price " + i + ": " + y.Text);
                        price = Convert.ToDecimal(y.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                TextBlock z = addProductDataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(addProductDataGrid.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
                if (z != null)
                {
                    if (!z.Text.Equals(""))
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Category " + i + ": " + z.Text);
                        categoryName = z.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                theSender.SendToDB(new product() { prodName = productName, prodPrice = price, prodCategoryName = categoryName });
            }

            foreach (product theT in db.products)
            {
                tempproduct.Add(theT);
            }

            productDataGrid.ItemsSource = tempproduct;
            addProductDataGrid.ItemsSource = new BindingList<TestGridItem>();
        }
    }
    private void cancelAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddInput.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        _currentDataGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

ADDITION INFORMATION

```
public class TestGridItem
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
    public string Four { get; set; }
}

addProductDataGrid.ItemsSource = new BindingList<TestGridItem>();
```